# Array de Objetos y valores

Tags: php

Tengo dos Clases, `Producto` cuyos atributos son un `id` y `precio`. En`Carrito`
cuyo atributo es un `array` del contenido agregado `Producto y cantidad`.

Pero en el `Index` a la hora de mostrar el contenido este me muestra el array vació y no se por que...

```
<?php

class Carrito {
    public $carrito;

    function __construct(){
        $this->carrito = array();
    }

    function add(Producto $productos, $cantidades){
        array_push($this->carrito,array($productos => $cantidades));
    }

    function getCarrito(){
        return $this->carrito;
    }
}

?>
```

```
<?php

class Producto
{
    public $id;
    public $precio;

    function __construct($id, $precio){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->precio = $precio;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

include('../php/clases/carrito.php');
include('../php/clases/producto.php');

$carrito = new Carrito();
$producto = new Producto(01,2000);

$carrito->add($producto, 2);

var_dump($carrito);

?>
```

La salida esperada debería ser el array con un producto y una cantidad de producto añadido...

Comment: No le pongas SOLUCIONADO al título de tu pregunta, con marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te ayudó alcanza

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 5):

el error efectivamente está en la función "add", creo que además deberías sumar las cantidades del producto en caso de existir previamente en el carrito para evitar que se duplique, he modificado la función para corregirla y evitar los duplicados:

```
function add(Producto $productos, $cantidades) {
  
    $productId = $productos->id;
    $qtyInCart = 0;

    if(isset($this->carrito[$productId]))
        $qtyInCart = $this->carrito[$productId]['qty'];
    
    $this->carrito[$productId] = array(
        'product' => $productos,
        'qty' => $qtyInCart + $cantidades
      );
}
```

un saludo y espero te sirva.

Answer (score 3):

El problema lo tienes en la función `add()` de la clase **Carrito.**

```
function add(Producto $productos, $cantidades){
  array_push($this->carrito,array($productos => $cantidades));
}
```

Estás tratando de establecer un array asociativo usando como clave un objeto, cosa que no se puede hacer.

Yo optaría por crear un `array` para tener por un lado el objeto y por otro la cantidad usando como claves dos `string`. Quedando la función `add()` de la siguiente manera:

```
function add(Producto $productos, $cantidades) {
  $producto = array(
    'producto' => $productos,
    'cantidad' => $cantidades
  );
        
  array_push($this->carrito, $producto);
}
```

**Referencia:** [array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Genial, gracias por la explicación y la aclaración !!